# Encrypted ZFS dataset fails to mount: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, zfs, nixos

I'm on NixOS and try to encrypt a hard drive partition (potentially more in the future) using ZFS. I tried to stick to [this guide](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/NixOS_on_ZFS), so I added

```
boot.zfs = {
  enableUnstable = true;
  requestEncryptionCredentials = true;
};
boot.supportedFilesystems = [ "zfs" ];
```

to my `configuration.nix`, and created the pool and dataset `zroot` and `zroot/genc` with `mountpoint=legacy acltype=posixacl xattr=sa`. I encrypted the pool with

```
$ sudo zfs create -o acltype=posixacl -o xattr=sa -o encryption=aes-256-gcm -o keyformat=passphrase -o mountpoint=none zroot/genc
```

I was asked for a passphrase,
and then I did

```
$ sudo zfs set mountpoint=legacy zroot/genc
$ sudo mount -t zfs zroot/genc /home/gecku/genc
$ sudo chown gecku:users ~/genc
$ touch ~/genc/hello
$ sudo nixos-generate-config
```

This all worked fine (I could create the file `~/genc/hello`). However, after `nixos-rebuild switch`, I was dropped into an emergency shell and couldn't do anything. I reverted to a previous version of NixOS, and removed the `zfs` entries from `/etc/nixos/hardware-configuration.nix` so that the system wouldn't try to import the ZFS pools (because apparently it failed at that). With this new configuration, I did

```
$ sudo zfs import zroot
$ sudo mount -t zfs zroot/genc ~/genc
> filesystem 'zroot/genc' can not be mounted: Permission denied
```

I did not get to a point where I was asked for my passphrase. `zroot/genc` has the attributes `canmount=on keylocation=prompt`.

So, how can I fix this? How can I mount the encrypted dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This guide](https://blog.heckel.xyz/2017/01/08/zfs-encryption-openzfs-zfs-on-linux/#Importing-a-pool-mounting-datasets-and-loading-keys) summarizes the mount process well. In short, you should probably use `zfs mount` instead of `mount -t zfs` because it will know to load / ask for encryption keys. To do this at boot time you can also use the `-l` flag to `zpool import` (although you’ll need some way to supply your boot script with the password).

Comment: This works! I also looked up the documentation for NixOS options again, and found [this](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#requestencryptioncredentials) -- it looks like encrypted ZFS datasets which are not *required* for boot cannot be loaded when `keylocation=prompt`. So I can either (1) put the key in a file, (2) try to edit the boot process manually or (3) format basically my entire hard drive to ZFS.

Comment: In addition, NixOS users can set `fileSystems."/home/gecku/genc".neededForBoot = true;` to force NixOS to ask for a passphrase for the ZFS partition during the boot process. Might be a bit hacky, but works.